# Can memory reads crash if write access is singleton?

Tags: c++, memory, thread-safety

Suppose I have a singleton memory (meaning I only write to it once). Suppose I have `Calculator` and `Printer`. `Calculator` manages `Printer` but doesn't have access to it on construction.

```
class Printer;

class Calculator {
  void read() {
    int result = 0;
    if (_printer != nullptr) {
       _print(result);
    }
  }

  // Assume `Printer` passed to us is unique
  void write(Printer* printer) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_lock);
    if (_printer == nullptr) {
      _printer = printer;
    }
  }

  std::mutex _lock;
  Printer _printer{nullptr};
}
```

As you can see, we're only going to initialize the memory once. Therefore, either the `_printer` is `null` (which is OK) or the `_printer` memory exists and we know with the singleton design that the memory won't be invalidated by future writes.

Is reading the memory safe at this point, or can thread races still cause crashes?

Comment: You might read the pointer while it us being written to, so the code will encounter Undefined Behaviour. Unless `read` and `write` are otherwise sequenced in code that isn't shown.

Comment: Where is the definition of `_print()`, do you mean `write()` instead? Also, what is the public API of that class? As it stands, it doesn't have any public members, making it pretty useless.

Comment: if you only call `write` once then the mutex is fairly pointless. You could use `std::atomic` instead

Comment: You should look into using [std::call_once](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) if you want to make sure an object is _initialized_ only once in a thread-safe manner. Then you can do away with the mutex and locking (depending on the rest of the code)

Comment: I'd address the design that got you here. Why can't you ensure `Calculator` is constructed after `Printer`? Do threads need to be involved?

Comment: The example is bogus, just wanted to put up something that shows the possibility of read during write. I think I have my answer that it is Undefined Behavior. 

> Why can't you ensure Calculator is constructed after Printer? Do threads need to be involved?

I can't, Printer is startup-critical to the application while Calculator would meaningfully regress performance if initialized during startup.

Answer (score 3):

No, that's undefined behavior for a data race.

Even if `write` is only called once, you need to make sure that there is synchronization with any possible `read` calls. Otherwise it is possible that a `read` is reading the pointer value while the single `write` is writing to it. The mutex doesn't impose any synchronization because you are not locking it in `read`.

Having one thread read a non-atomic object while another is writing to it without synchronization is a data race which is always undefined behavior.

There is no point in arguing about the possible value of the pointer in the `if`. Reading the value in itself is a data race and causes undefined behavior.

For a non-atomic object there is neither any guarantee that a new value will be written atomically, nor that it won't be stored speculatively early, nor that other values won't be invented that could be read by the other thread, nor that there won't be reordering of instructions from the compiler or CPU, nor that the store will become visible to the other thread at all. But all of that is just examples of how UB can manifest.

You need to also lock the mutex in `read` or use a `std::atomic<Printer*>` with acquire/release semantics instead.